# Issue: Dependencies not installed in Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using visual studio 2017 version 15.7.3 to create asp.net core 2.0 project with the Angular template. The project created but dependencies give a warning that npm isn't installed properly.

[image]

[image]

When I run the project. I got these errors:

[image]

Comment: What version of node do you have installed?

Comment: did you try to run `npm restore` and `dotnet restore`?